# Reload a div without refresh all page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have a question. So, In my project I have a div :

```
<div class="right-bloc-pub-1">
   <script src="http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23" type="text/javascript">
</div>
```

No, I want to reload this script when a button is reload. I tried :

```
location.reload();
```

But it's reload all the page. It's possible to reload onlye the  right-bloc-pub-1 with his script?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="text/javascript">
   function load_js()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'source_file.js';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   load_js();
</script>
```

The main point is inserting a new script tag -- you can remove the old one without consequence. You may need to add a timestamp to the query string if you have caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) with url and class selector.

```
$( "#ID" ).load( "http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23 .right-bloc-pub-1" );
```

[Loading Page Fragments](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

Comment: I tried like this : 
`$( ".right-bloc-pub-1" ).load("http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23 .right-bloc-pub-1");` but not work\

Comment: Can you explain what is not working, do you get call on server? are you getting any error in javascript/jquery?

Comment: I call on server the script : I get in console : `GET ...` with red color

Comment: So, in console I get with red : `GET http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23 OK 903ms`. And `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: And the script is not reloaded

Comment: This seems cross domain request problem, you need to fix that

Comment: How to fix this issue? I use apache server

Comment: Is the url http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23 belongs to the website of current page?, as the error suggest you are trying to access page from other website

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to reload the script, like this:

```
function reload()
{
    $.getScript('http://www.adcash.com/ad/display.php?r=23');
    return true;
}
```

You can also make it refresh every x milliseconds, you do this like so:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){ reload; }, 3000);//Every 3 seconds

//To stop refreshing
clearInterval(intervalID);
```